# Did this woman mean what I think she meant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

At the beginning of the DS9 episode Necessary Evil, a Bajoran woman named Vaatrik Pallra approaches Quark, enlisting his aid in recovering a box hidden in what used to be her late husband's shop on Deep Space Nine. In addition to promising Quark some latinum she offers "Her personal gratitude".

What she means by personal gratitude is never specified, but part of me has always suspected this was her way of offering sexual favors- can anyone confirm or disprove this?

---

Transcript:

> QUARK: You didn't call me to Bajor to talk about tea.
> PALLRA: No. I need a favour.
> QUARK: For old times sake?
> PALLRA: That's right.
> QUARK: I'm still as kind as ever.
> PALLRA: I can pay you.
> QUARK: I'm listening. 
> [details]
> PALLRA: And I can pay you five bars of latinum.
> QUARK: Five?
> PALLRA: And as always my personal gratitude.
> QUARK: A day, maybe two.

([source](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/428.htm))

Comment: I tend to agree the subtext there implies sexual favors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The script notes on the [original screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/428.txt) indicates that that's ***precisely*** what she means. Along with the financial compensation (which isn't *quite enough* to incentivise him to do the job), she'll also have sex with him. Note that he goes from 'uncertain' to highly motivated immediately.

> **QUARK:** **(uncertain)** *Five...?*
>
> **PALLRA:** *And as always... my personal gratitude.*
>
> A beat as Quark studies her... the lightning flickers, **she's irresistible... no matter how tough he plays it, he knows it** and what's worse, so does she.  He nods, rises.
>
> **QUARK:** *A day.  Maybe two.*
>
> **She smiles with promise.**  He leaves.  A beat later, a heavy  set, muscular man (TRAZKO) appears from the shadows of the other room.  Pallra glances at him with cold eyes...
> everything went exactly as planned.

In the original script she was having an affair with Dukat so it's not out of character for her to use sex as a bargaining tool.

Comment: Thank God that's cleared up. Leaving that line ambiguous would have ruined the whole Star Trek business.

Comment: That's Quark's problem. If he chased latinum like he chased oo-mox, he'd own that moon by now.

Comment: Quark is observant of Rule of Acquisition #40 - *She can touch your lobes but never your latinum.*